# How to Connect MXQ-4K Android TV Box to Android Studio on Linux

Tags: android, linux, adb, fedora, android-tv

I am trying to connect an Android TV box by the model MXQ-4K to my development computer (Intel Core i7 - 4970k) running Android Studio 3.1 on Fedora Linux. There is some info at [google android docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_tv) most of which (except registrations) I followed. I still do not see the device listed in Android Studio when I connect the two device via an AM-AM usb cable. 
Another thing I tried for connecting is `adb connect <ipaddr>` and `adb connect <ipaddr>:port`, where `ipaddr` is the LAN IP address of the target TV box. Doing so, I receive a `connection refused` error.

Last, but not least I have enabled USB debugging on the device.
I am really frustrated that this device does not have a micro-usb input just like a typical Android phone, and such development operations seem not to have been predicted by default.
So, are there any workarounds on Linux or on the device itself (it is **rooted** fortunately) I can make use of to solve this issue?

**Update**:
It seems the manufacturer uses a specific driver for Windows enabling the user to update firmware for the device using the same A-A USB cable.

Comment: have you first tried with usb, because for wireless debugging first you have to connect with usb. Then use commands

Comment: @RanjanDas sure I have

Comment: @Ranjan I think you should add your comment in  somewhat more details as an answer.

Comment: @codezombie I also have the exact same issue. Unable to get it detected on Android Studio the issue. There is no USB Type B port. Any update on this ?

Comment: Rahul you can use debugging over ip as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm debugging with adb and logcat. So you can miss this steps, while connecting to the STB:

- Launch Android Studio with root permission.
- Activate developer mode by clicking on the `Build` in the `About` section inside `Settings`.
- After `adb connect <ip address>` there is a alert menu, like on the image below:
  [image]

Also [here](http://www.mikevandrongelen.info/2015/12/apps-on-big-screen-iii-debugging-android-tv.html) is the article of how to use adb.